# Не идет парсинг в BeautifulSoup на python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

В общем этот код должен парсить название продуктов но в консоли выводит пустую строку. Хочу узнать почему не работает и заранее спасибо.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def parse():
    URL = 'https://haribo-shop.ru/catalog/zhevatelnie_konfety/'
    HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}

    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'item ')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({'title': item.find('a', class_ = 'name').get_text(strip = True)})

    for comp in comps:
        print(comp['title'])

parse()
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему то в строке `items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'item ')` вы пытаетесь  найти класс "item", хотя нужен `'div', class_='name-cont part'`

Класса item, там вообще не видно, но может и просмотрел

```
    def parse():
        URL = 'https://haribo-shop.ru/catalog/zhevatelnie_konfety/'
        HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}
    
        response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
        soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all('div', class_='name-cont part')
        comps = []
    
        for item in items:
            comps.append({'title': item.find('div', class_ = 'name').get_text(strip = True)})
    
        for comp in comps:
            print(comp['title'])
    
    parse()

Но вообще можно сразу  искать и class_ = 'name'

def parse():
    URL = 'https://haribo-shop.ru/catalog/zhevatelnie_konfety/'
    HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}

    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    names = soup.find_all('div', class_='name')
    comps = []

    for name in names:
        comps.append({'title': name.get_text(strip = True)})

    for comp in comps:
        print(comp['title'])

parse()
```

Comment: Сорян пацаны я напутал классы, ща все работает